# Selected items from listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I read all items from listbox:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
                {                
                    {
                       sb.Append(item.ToString());
                       sb.Append(" "); 
                    }

                }
```

How read only selected items?

Comment: Use the selectedItem property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedItems` Property to get all selected Items and then loop through them to append it to the string builder.

```
 foreach (var listitem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
 {             
    sb.Append(listitem.ToString());
    sb.Append(" "); 
 }
```